# Star Wars: Galactic Battlegrounds/Age of Empires BSOD Windows 7 32-bit

Tags: technical-issues, windows, age-of-empires, star-wars-galactic-battlegrounds

I found Star Wars: Galactic Battlegrounds on an ancient drive so, full of hopes of retro gaming, I cranked it up on Windows 7 (laptop, Core 2 duo, 32bit, 3(4)gig ram, intel 945 integrated graphics).  It did cut-scenes (many happy memories, much expectation) and then BSOD'd (boo).

Tried compatibility settings but no dice - BSOD.  Tried XP mode but it gives a DirectDraw error although the prerequisites app says all well.

I looked into the recent Gog re-release but the EXE has the same date as mine making me think it's the same release repackaged and so it will exhibit thr same problem.

Age of Empires behaves exactly the same (SWGB is a skin of AOA AFAIK?).

Anyone any ideas? Other than get a life perhaps?

Comment: Good question and well detailed, this is the sort of question that I actually want to answer.

Comment: Ahh! SWGB! I still play this all the time on Windows 7 AND 10!

Comment: As far as I know, GOG should work fine. I still have my CD but no CD drive so I had to torrent mine (which is legal because I actually own it), and it works absolutely fine on Windows 10. I think there *may* have been some compatability issue with DirectX Draw or something like that on Windows 7, but 10 renders it fine.

Comment: Infact that DirectDraw error might be good for you. Extract from [**here**](http://swgb.heavengames.com/cgi-bin/forums/display.cgi?action=ct&f=1,61933,60,all):

Right click on the Battlegrounds icon and press `Properties`>`Compatibility`>`Run this program in compatibility..`>`Reduced color mode`>`Run in 640..`.>`Apply`>`OK`.

Tell me how you go!

Comment: I tried forcing 256 colours  and 640 x 480 ) separately and in combination but no luck. Nonetheless Syscheck gives pass for directX drivers. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it.  Took the xp mode vhd, loaded it in oracle virtualbox and added a graphic card. runs fine.